# Server for iPhone; continuous connection

Tags: iphone, sockets, ios8, stream, server

Ok lets  say I want to create a connection between my iPhone app and my server (i'd like to try and use GoDaddy servers for this) to server real time location data to users.

I've seen plenty of good stuff online about using sockets, streams, ASIHttpmessage, CFHTTPMessageRef, etc., but what I'm unclear about is how to set up a server that continuously servers real time data to users (I believe you'd need a stream of data going to the user for this, not just a single http request and response).  How does one take a host like GoDaddy and run server code on it.  I know you can set up a server like this using terminal, but I don't have access to command line or the ability to run this "server program" from my web host as far as I know.  Is there software I can download on my cpanel for this?  Do I need a virtual private server and different hosting via GoDaddy maybe?

Does anyone know how I can do this or if my understanding of this whole thing is wrong.  Please keep in mind I need this real time (or close to). Please, educate me.  I really just need a better understanding of how this works.

Comment: I think you're thinking about it the wrong way around. You'd typically have your *app* poll the server for new information, rather than trying to push data from your server to clients.

Comment: So is polling the survey for data the same as setting up a socket via a stream and getting data.  I've read that it's better done that way so the app doesn't have to write the data to disk, it just reads from the stream straight to where your using it.  You know so theres a constant connection, not a series of http requests (just asking).  Also are you saying my app should continuously send out requests for new data and wait for responses?  Thanks for the quick response.